# coreData and collectionView slowing app

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobject, collectionview

I presently have an array of managedObjects which is the model for my collectionView.  The collectionView populates it's cells by accessing the various properties of the managedObject in the array at the appropriate indexPath.  I have noticed my collectionView scrolling is not smooth and wondering if I am going about this the wrong way and perhaps I should change my approach.

my model is an array of messages stored in coreData:

```
> var messages = [NSManagedObject]()
```

in my cellForItemAtIndexPath I populate the textView's by referring to the messages array:

> cell.textView.text = messages[indexPath].valueForKey("text") as! String

My question is whether or not this is an efficient way to populate a collectionView or if accessing coreData is slowing my app and there may be a better approach.  Thx

Below is the result of looking at instruments.  The first value is just an address but seems to be taking up a lot of time.  Not sure how to find out the method from just the address value of the symbol...

[image]

Comment: Can you post some code to get some idea ?

Comment: I have edited the question to add some code.  Basically though I was just wondering if there is a better way to populate a collectionView with data stored in coreData or if this approach is fine.  Thx

Comment: Operating on NSManagedObjects is absolutely fine and should not be the performance killer in your case. There must be another thing that slows down the collectionview, but you need to show more code to get an idea.

Comment: Thanks Julian.  There is not much more to my collectionView.  I have added a screenshot of the Time Profiler.  I don't know what the first value that is just an address is in the Symbol Name area. Or maybe it's to do with my storyboard constraints for the textView.  I will try to work through it and find out what is wrong.  Thanks for letting me know about the core data.

Comment: How are you populating the array? Why aren't you using a fetched results controller?

Comment: i am doing using an NSFetchRequest: try managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) and assigning this to the array.  Actually this is my first app so I'm not that familiar with the fetched results controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not the core data and collecting view. It is `UITextView` that you have used inside collection view. Replace it with `UILabel` and your application will go smooth.

I had same problem and I resolved that by doing what I suggested. But till now I don't why this worked.

Comment: thank you.  I considered to do that but I need some of the formatting for links etc which seems very clunky with a label.

Comment: i may throw in the towel and follow your suggestion.  I suspect it has to do with the constraints of the textView

Comment: @alionthego For the links `NSAttributedString` may come to rescue. And, I am sorry I really could't figure out why it worked. I may be look into it and post the edit in future.

Comment: You were right about the textView.  I changed to label and the choppiness and lag were gone instantly with all the same constraints etc...  The problem is now I don't have my links underlined and clickable despite using an attributed text.  I think I can use a clunky solution to overcome that but it's nice to know exactly what the problem was.  I may tinker with textView again and see if I can figure out what is causing the lag.  Thanks again for your help.